# Django password reset email link redirects to login page

Tags: python, django

I am using custom forms to override the Django templates but when a user clicks reset password and receives the email with the password reset link, etc (EDITED QUESTION TO CHANGE ORDER FROM `reset-password` to `password-reset`)

`/reset/OA/50l-94673624f6b9fa5a060a/`

When the link is clicked it redirects to

`/account/login/`

It should be directing them to

`/password-reset/confirm/`

and then to

`/password-reset/complete/`

The command line looks like this when reset link is clicked

```
GET /reset/OA/50l-94673624f6b9fa5a060a/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
GET /account/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2237
```

LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS

```
LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS = {
    r'^account/logout/$',
    r'^account/register/$',
    r'^account/password-reset/$',
    r'^account/password-reset/done/$',
    r'^account/password-reset/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>,+)/$',
    r'^account/password-reset/complete/$',

}
```

urls.py

```
app_name='accounts'

from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView, LogoutView, PasswordResetView, PasswordResetDoneView, PasswordResetConfirmView, PasswordResetCompleteView
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^login/$', LoginView.as_view(template_name='accounts/login.html'), name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', LogoutView.as_view(template_name='accounts/logout.html'), name='logout'),
    url(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register'),
    url(r'^profile/$', views.view_profile, name='view_profile'),
    url(r'^profile/edit$', views.edit_profile, name='edit_profile'),
    url(r'^change-password/$', views.change_password, name='change_password'),

    url(r'^password-reset/$',
    PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='accounts/password_reset.html',
    success_url=reverse_lazy('accounts:password_reset_done')),
    {'email_template_name': 'accounts/password_reset_email.html'},
    name='password_reset'),

    url(r'^password-reset/done/$',
    PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='accounts/password_reset_done.html'),
    name='password_reset_done'),

    url(r'^password-reset/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>,+)/$',
    PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='accounts/password_reset_confirm.html'),
    name='password_reset_confirm'),

    url(r'^password-reset/complete/$',
    PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='accounts/password_reset_complete.html'),
    name='password_reset_complete'),

]
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'accounts',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

middleware.py

```
import re

from django.conf import settings
from django.urls import reverse
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib.auth import logout

EXEMPT_URLS = [re.compile(settings.LOGIN_URL.lstrip('/'))]
if hasattr(settings, 'LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS'):
    EXEMPT_URLS += [re.compile(url) for url in settings.LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS]

class LoginRequiredMiddleware:

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        assert hasattr(request, 'user')
        path = request.path_info.lstrip('/')
        url_is_exempt = any(url.match(path) for url in EXEMPT_URLS)

        if path == reverse('accounts:logout').lstrip('/'):
            logout(request)

        if request.user.is_authenticated and url_is_exempt:
            return redirect(settings.LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)
        elif request.user.is_authenticated or url_is_exempt:
            return None

        else:
            return redirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)
```

password_reset_email.html

```
{% load i18n %}{% autoescape off %}
{% blocktrans %} You're recieving this email because you requested a password reset
for your user account at {{ site_name }}.{% endblocktrans %}

{% trans "Please go to the following page and choose a new password:" %}
{% block reset_link %}
{{ protocol }}://{{ domain }}{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}
{% endblock %}
{% trans "Your username, in case you've forgotten:" %} {{ user.get_username }}

{% trans "Thank you for using x!" %}

{% blocktrans %}The {{ site_name }} team{% endblocktrans %}

{% endautoescape %}
```

Comment: `user.is_authenticated` will always return `False` if the user is logged out as it becomes `AnonymousUser.is_authenticated` . And why would a logged in user reset his password. And I guess for that reason your `process_view` always does `return redirect(settings.LOGIN_URL)`

Comment: You need to make sure that your password reset URLs are included in `LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS`. It might be useful for you to show your email template - the URL in your question `/reset/OA/50l-94673624f6b9fa5a060a/` does not seem to match your URL pattern `r'^reset-password/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>,+)/$',`.

Comment: Note that final view should use `PasswordResetCompleteView`. You have `PasswordResetConfirmView` twice. I suggest you use the [same names as Django does](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#using-the-views), e.g. `password_reset_complete`. Switching the order to `reset_password_complete` makes it confusing to other Django users.

Comment: @VineethSai Thank you, how would I go about changing that so that only a logged out user has the ability to reset password?

Comment: @Alasdair Thank you I have now switched around all my names to match the Django template. The `PasswordResetConfirmView` was mistyped twice so I've now corrected that, thank you. My password reset URL is included in `LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS` I will update my question to include the email template. Even after all of this the `password_reset_email` link still redirects to `account/login/`

Comment: @Trillz Try changing this `request.user.is_authenticated` to this `request.user.is_authenticated()` in your `middleware.py` and let me know if it worked. and btw what django version are you using.

Comment: @VineethSai I'm using 2.1.2 and when I change it to `request.user.is_authenticated()` it throws an error `'bool' object is not callable`

Comment: @Trillz Could you try changing the `LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS` to a tuple rather than a set ?

So it must be `LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS = ( )` not `{ }`

Comment: @VineethSai Just tried changing to a tuple but `password_reset_email` link still redirects to login page and doesn't show the screen `password_reset_confirm`

Answer (score 3):

Change in the settings section the confirmed part to just account/password-rest/confirm/ without dollar sign so everything after that URL will be exempt as well.

```
LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS = {
  r'^account/logout/$',
  r'^account/register/$',
  r'^account/password-reset/$',
  r'^account/password-reset/done/$',
  r'^account/password-reset/confirm/',
  r'^account/password-reset/complete/$',
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change from `PasswordResetConfirmView` to `PasswordResetCompleteView`.

`PasswordResetCompleteView` presents a view which informs the user that password has been successfully changed. You don't need to write `PasswordResetConfirmView` twice.

Change to

```
url(r'^reset-password/complete/$',
PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='accounts/reset_password_complete.html'),
name='reset_password_complete'),
```

For more detail, check django docs. (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.PasswordResetCompleteView)

Comment: Thanks, I totally didn't realise I mistyped `ConfirmView` twice!

Comment: The email link still redirects to `account/login/`

Answer (score 0):

You have included your password reset URLs in a `urls.py` which has `app_name = 'accounts'`, therefore you need to include the `accounts` namespace when reversing the URLs.

```
{% url 'accounts:password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}
```

As an aside, I've seen several questions on Stack Overflow where namespacing the password reset URLs caused problems. In my opinion, it's simpler to include the password reset URLs in a `urls.py` that does not use a namespace.

The log line `GET /reset/OA/50l-94673624f6b9fa5a060a/` suggests that you have included the password reset URLs in a second place. I would try to track down this extra include and remove it.

Comment: Hi Alasdair, thanks for the help I really appreciate it. I did have the namespace in the email template as `{% url 'accounts:password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}` however it threw this error `NoReverseMatch at /account/password-reset/ Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' with keyword arguments '{'uidb64': 'NA', 'token': '50l-b062bef8209ab6b2b65d'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['account/password-reset/confirm/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z]+)-(?P<token>,+)/$']` and when I took out the namespace it went to `password_reset_done` page where it says `We've emailed you instructions etc`

Comment: How would you go about tracking down the extra include? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: `(?P<token>,+)` looks like a mistake. Look at the regex [used in Django 1.11](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.11/django/contrib/auth/urls.py#L18), or since you are using Django 2.0, consider [switching to path](https://github.com/django/django/blob/2.1/django/contrib/auth/urls.py#L18).

Comment: To find the extra include, you just need to search your `urls.py` files for `password_reset_confirm`. You may have `include('django.contrib.auth.urls')` somewhere.

Comment: Okay, thank you, I've now switched everything over to path so am using `reset/<uidb64>/<token>/` but the reset password link still redirects to the login page? And there is no other instance of `password_reset_confirm`

Comment: I found `include('django.contrib.auth.urls')` in the main app `urls.py` folder under `urlpatterns = ` and removed it but still same probem

Comment: Did you remember to fix the regex in `LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS`? It would be simpler to use one regex that matched all the reset urls, e.g. `r'^account/password-reset/'`, instead of exact regexes for each pattern.

Comment: Thank you!! I think that managed to do it!! I also had to move all the .htmls except `password_reset_email.html` out of `templates/registration/` and into `templates/accounts/` and also add `success_url=reverse_lazy('accounts:password_reset_complete')` into the `path('password-reset/confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/'`